# Terraform Block Resource Failing on Syntax

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a formatting issue that I cannot figure out. The soa_record seems to fail on the email. Maybe the soa_record block is not being defined correctly?

Code and error below.

```
variable "private_dns_zones" {
  description = "A list of Private DNS Zones and their properties."
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    resource_group_name = string
    tags                = map(string)
    soa_record = object({
      email        = string
      expire_time  = number
      minimum_ttl  = number
      refresh_time = number
      retry_time   = number
      ttl          = number
    })
  }))
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "this" {
  for_each            = { for n in var.private_dns_zones : "${n.name}" => n } #name of private dns zone is unique
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = each.value.resource_group_name
  tags                = merge(data.azurerm_resource_group.this[each.value.resource_group_name].tags, each.value.tags)
  soa_record = {
    email        = each.value.soa_record.email
    expire_time  = each.value.soa_record.expire_time
    minimum_ttl  = each.value.soa_record.minimum_ttl
    refresh_time = each.value.soa_record.refresh_time
    retry_time   = each.value.soa_record.retry_time
    ttl          = each.value.soa_record.ttl
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
╷
│ Error: "soa_record.0.email" only contains letters, numbers, underscores, dashes and periods
│ 
│   with module.private_dns_zones.azurerm_private_dns_zone.this["zone1.local"],
│   on Modules/privatednszone/main.tf line 22, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "this":
│   22:     email        = each.value.soa_record.email
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: "soa_record.0.email" only contains letters, numbers, underscores, dashes and periods
│ 
│   with module.private_dns_zones.azurerm_private_dns_zone.this["zone2.local"],
│   on Modules/privatednszone/main.tf line 22, in resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "this":
│   22:     email        = each.value.soa_record.email
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `private_dns_zones`?

Comment: Seems I cannot submit any more code examples. A snippet of the .tfvars file is here instead. private_dns_zones = [
  {
    name                = "zone1.local"
    resource_group_name = "Terraform1"
    tags = {
      dns = "zone1"
    }
    soa_record = {
      email        = "xxx@xyz.com"
      expire_time  = 2419200
      minimum_ttl  = 10
      refresh_time = 3600
      retry_time   = 300
      ttl          = 3000
    }
  }
]

Comment: You can edit your question and provide the example in a correctly formatted code block.

Comment: yep. tried that. says it's too long.

Comment: Is soa_record = object({}) not the correct format for a block?

Comment: This error message seems to be coming from the AzureRM provider https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/b7b600ac93f7e947b840d6822b33454a7614545e/internal/services/privatedns/validate/private_dns_zone_soa_record_email.go#L35-L38 and is rejecting that the email address contains any characters outside of the classes indicated. It's a kinda confusing error message, but I _think_ it's trying to say that it _should_ only contain those character classes, and so it's rejecting some other character you included.

Comment: Given the context, I'd guess that this is trying to require a hostname-approximation of an email address, with the `@` replaced by a `.`, and so perhaps the problem here is that you've got a real `@` in there which you need to replace with a period to get a valid SOA "RNAME" field value. 

Comment: fascinating. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/dns/record-set/soa?view=azure-cli-latest) you will find that they use `email` format without `@`. For example:

```
--email myhostmaster.mysite.com
```

Thus I guess, that you have to follow same format in TF.

Comment: Correct. I just tried it in the Azure portal and it comes up with the same error as TF. Thank you!!! It also seems to want an email server and not an actual email address.